# Showing a matrix in rust doc comments

Tags: rust, rustdoc

I would like to show a matrix (mathematical entity) in rust doc comments. I tried using this:

```
/**
For example, given the projection matrix:

        1   0   0   0
        
        1   0   0   0

        1   0   0   0

        1   0   0   0
*/
```

While it looks acceptable in the code, the generated comments seem to remove the extra spaces between each matrix element. It looks something like this:

[image]

What would be the best way to format this matrix correctly? Or is this the best I'm going to get?

My IDE is VS Code, with extension rust-analyser installed only.

UPDATE:

It does not seem to be an IDE issue, as the generated docs using `cargo doc --open` shows similarly un-formatted matrix:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the IDE you are using. If you look at the output generated by rustdoc (`cargo doc --open` will generate documentation and open it in your browser), it looks good (because of the indentation, the matrix is formatted as code). Therefore, please add information about your IDE setup.

Comment: Oh, didn't know it was due to the IDE.. my IDE is VS Code, which should be pretty common one I'd imagine. Updated question

Comment: Trying adding three backticks each on the lines before and after the matrix.  Then indent the whole thing (including the backticks) by 4 spaces, since it seems to be inside a list.

Comment: @L.F. Looks much better after doing this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a matrix generated from LaTeX, you can use the macro I've written: https://github.com/JohnScience/include_display_mode_tex